# HighCharts BoxPlot With Multiple Series Having Single Data

Tags: highcharts

Using the `type: 'boxplot'` chart I am trying to set up a view of some wage data. The data consists of multiple occupations and their wage values for low, q1, median, q3, high. My issue is that each occupation just has one set of those 5 points. So, I have 14 occupations in this example with 14 distinct series values (of the 5 wage values). Each series looks like this:

```
{
     name: 'Computer and Information Research Scientists',
     data: [
          [68834.77, 85124.14, 107734.77, 131196.33, 157504.48]
          ],
     tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>{point.key}</em><br/>'
     }
}
```

The chart renders the 14 box "points" fine. However the xAxis (which I have inverted but it is the same if not inverted) just shows the first `category` title and appends that to the tooltip text box and no other category names appear on the xAxis. I thought it was the `tooltip` code in each series but removing that still has the labeling wrong. My example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/LrLLU/). How can I maintain category names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see, each series has only one point, so doesn't contain x-value, so assumed `pointStart` is 0, and `pointInterval` is 1 (for categorized axis).

If you chave only one point per series, I advice to add x-value, which is also category index, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/LrLLU/2/

Comment: I see that it works in your example. But, why is it not using the category location given in the `xAxis.categories` list?

Comment: Series name isn't linked to category name.

Comment: I meant by index. But I can see how it would be hard to tell - such as if a series has no data which index is it in? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also, not related to this post but I am seeing "drift" in the centering of the boxplot 'point' within the category label. See http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/LrLLU/4/

Comment: Set `grouping: false`: http://jsfiddle.net/LrLLU/7/. However, why won't you use just one series, like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/LrLLU/6/

Comment: Because I am dumb...looks like my brain is already heading into the 3 day weekend. If possibly I would upvote your answer again.